# Can a process be started from another process running on a Citrix server?

Tags: process, virtualization, citrix, xenapp

I have a C# application that currently runs locally and starts Excel programmatically.  I now need to install my application on a Citrix server and publish it so that it is used exclusively through Citrix (XenApp 5.0).

Questions:

- Will my application still be able to kick off Excel even when running on a Citrix server?
- Will Excel be started on the same Citrix server as the original app within the farm?
- Will the users of the app be able to see Excel (i.e. will it be streamed to their client)?
- Does Citrix (or my application) need to be configured in any specific way to make the above work?

Any help on the above questions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Will my application still be able to kick off Excel even when running on a Citrix server?

=> Yes, of course make sure your app is only installed on servers that also have Excel installed.

Will Excel be started on the same Citrix server as the original app within the farm?

=> Yes.

Will the users of the app be able to see Excel (i.e. will it be streamed to their client)?

=> Yes.

Does Citrix (or my application) need to be configured in any specific way to make the above work?

=> No.

Running under Citrix generally isn't going to do anything weird on unusual with your app. You can do most of the things you can do running your app locally on a desktop. Any visible windows that are running in the users' session will get remoted to the client. When you are running an app published via Citrix you have a full session running on the server. The reason you don't see the entire server desktop however is due to a feature called seamless windows. Citrix HDX technology detects all the windows in your session and just shows those windows on your local device like they're running as a local app.